# Spring Boot + MySQL5: Errcode 13

Tags: java, mysql, windows, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application, I am accessing a MySQL 5 database for user management. However, whenever I start my application and the tables already exist, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.kehrbusch.butler.authentication.app.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error accessing column metadata: butler-test.u_authority
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getColumn(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getColumn(TableInformationImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlAlterStrings(Table.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.migrateTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql1068_9_2.MYI' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:875) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1991) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3403) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:470) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3105) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2336) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2729) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2430) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.IterateBlock.doForAll(IterateBlock.java:50) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:2339) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getColumn(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:454) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]


... 32 common frames omitted
```

In my application.properties file, I set the option `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update`.

What is causing this permission error? (I am running XAMPP on Windows 10 and the XAMPP folder is located in the C drive's root directory)

Comment: See if this helps: http://beerpla.net/2010/01/05/how-to-fix-intermittent-mysql-errcode-13-errors-on-windows/

Comment: I came about this post as well, but unfortunately this didn't do the trick